Good models for building/tree detection
I need to estimate the speed of a car by analysing a dashcam video that provides a view of the street in front. I had the idea of tracking objects that I know are stationary (buildings/trees) and calculate their relative speed in order to do this. However, I didn't find any good models for detecting/tracking buildings/trees in a street view, most of them just detect cars and persons.
Are there any good pretrained models for this?
